# Should we start giving constructive criticism when questions are closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have had several questions of mine closed, and I did learn my lesson when the question was closed. But, I feel like we could be more specific not about *why* the question was closed, but about what we could do *in the future* to improve the user's future questions and maybe give the closed question a new life? I think we should do this and start giving more specific reasons for closing questions.

Comment: Can you provide examples where you thought the feedback was lacking?